# Excel validate a specific string combination eg: g.2016.10.s

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have possible values of

(g|m|j).YYYY.MM.s
or
(g|m|j).[4 digits].[2 digits].s

eg: g.2016.10.s

Is there somebody with hot formula skills who can quickly help me on that or give a hint? I cant figure it out.

Comment: You haven't stated what your issue is. What do you want to have at the end? What have you tried so far? Where is the error in your code?

Comment: Hint, using AND() and OR() for the logic and LEFT(),RIGHT(), and MID() for the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select the cell **A1** and then go to **Data > Data Tools > Data Validation** and then in **Settings** change **Allow** to **Custom** and write this formula:

```
=AND(OR(MID(A1,1,1)="g",MID(A1,1,1)="m",MID(A1,1,1)="j"),MID(A1,2,1)=".",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,3,4))),MID(A1,7,1)=".",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,8,2))),MID(A1,10,1)=".",MID(A1,11,1)="s", LEN(A1)=11)
```

then hit OK and try writing something.